# How to provide API data to react-native-snap-carousel

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

i am using react-native-snap-carousel for my first react-native app.

I have read docs but i see it use static data. But i want to get data form server with API, how can i do it?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from the server and pass it like so:

```
class MyCoponent extends React.Component{

   state = { data: null }

   fetchData = () => {
      // const result = fetch from api ... 
      this.setState(() => ({ data: result }))
   }

   render(){
      const { data } = this.state
      if(!data){
         return <Text>No data</Text>
      }
      return(
         <Carousel data={data}/>
      )
   }

}
```

Comment: i have fetch data from server and pass it, app no error but it didn't show the image. what wrong? i follow this example https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/tree/master/example